# React native macos Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, promise, child-process

I am getting the following error can you tell me where I am doing wrong.

If you think there is a way to write the function better let me know.

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

```json
"dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.13",
    "react-native-childprocess": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-macos": "^0.71.0-0"
}
```

```js
function shell(pwd, cmd) {
    return useCallback(async (pwd, cmd) => {
      return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = spawn('/bin/sh', ['-c', cmd], { pwd,
          stdout: (o) => resolve(o),
          stderr: (o) => reject(o),
          terminate: (o) => o,
        });
        console.log(data)
      });
    }, [pwd, cmd]);
  }

let a = shell('/Users/', 'ls')
      .then(a => console.log("a", a))
      .catch(console.error)
      .finally(a => console.log("b", a));
```

Answer (score 0):

`useCallback` cannot using inside a pure function.

Correct code:

```js
  const shell = useCallback(async (pwd, cmd) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const data = spawn('/bin/sh', ['-c', cmd], {
        pwd,
        stdout: o => resolve(o),
        stderr: o => reject(o),
        terminate: o => o,
      })
      console.log(data)
    })
  }, [])
```

Comment: Ok, it seems to work some considerations.

1) Previously inside useEffect I did something like this inside the return: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUyIL.png

Do you think it is correct to do so in this case too?

2) How do you think I should handle `terminate`?

https://github.com/RockyF/react-native-childprocess/blob/master/src/index.tsx#L46

Comment: 1) Depend on what do you want to do with `shell` function. `useCallback` almost like a function, and you should use as an action like run when press a button.
2) I don't understand your question